# F# Check if a list is empty

Tags: f#, functional-programming

As an F# newbie, I am trying to implement a simple function which takes an index and a list as parameters then returns the list value of the given index.

```
let rec getElementAtIndex (index : int) (list : 'a list) = 
  match index, list with
    | _ ,[] -> failwith "index is greater than number of elements in list.."
    | _, _ when index < 0 -> failwith "index is less than 0." 
    | 0, (first::_) -> first
    | _, (_::rest') -> getElementAtIndex (index - 1) rest'
```

My solution works fine but when I give the index parameter greater than the list size and when I give an empty list as parameter, in both situations goes in to the same condition which is

```
| _ ,[] -> failwith "index is greater than number of elements in list."
```

How can i avoid this and check if the list is empty and given index is greater than list size separately without using .net library methods?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The error message looks correct in both cases. What's the problem?

Comment: I think checking whether a list is empty and checking whether a given index is out of range or not are different things.

Comment: If you're happy with the inefficiency of traversing the list to determine its length, you can use `List.length`.

Comment: @molbdnilo is there way to do it with out library functions ?

Comment: It's trivial to write `length` yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pattern for checking *global* preconditions is to nest functions, that is check the preconditions first and then start recursing with the *actual* work. This way, the recursive function gets simpler and there is no need for `when` guards or `length`:

```
let getElementAtIndex index list =
  if index < 0 then failwith "index is less than 0"
  if List.isEmpty list then failwith "list is empty"
  let rec get = function
    | _ , [] -> failwith "index is greater than number of elements in list"
    | 0, first::_ -> first
    | _, _::rest -> get(index - 1, rest)
  get(index, list)
```

The `function` syntax is a shortcut for:

```
  let rec get i l =
    match i, l with
    | _ , [] -> failwith "index is greater than number of elements in list"
    | 0, first::_ -> first
    | _, _::rest -> get (index - 1) rest
```

**Update**

Instead of `if List.isEmpty list then failwith "list is empty"` you can use `match list with [] -> failwith "..." | _ -> ()` or `if list = [] then failwith "..."` The latter only works for lists of elements supporting equality.

Comment: I have already done that in my solution. I want to be able to check if the given list parameter is an empty list without using helper functions fron .net library.

Comment: @Tartar, this solution achieves to distinguish between the error cases you have asked for. There are no .NET functions used here at all. If the `isEmpty` property is the reason for objection, that is actually a simple match against an actual empty list, see https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/list.fs#L138