# Identify If The List Is Empty

Tags: list, if-statement, f#, pattern-matching

I am entirely new to F# I have this function that calculates the sum of the two different `x` and `y` points like this `let vAdd (x1, y1) (x2, y2) : float * float = (x1 + x2, y1 + y2)` and then I have another function that takes a list of the points and then uses `vAdd` to do the calculation. `let vSum [(x1, y1); (x2, y2)] = vAdd (x1, y1) (x2, y2)`

Now my question would be, how would I check and throw some error if the list given is empty? I tried with  `if ... then failwith "list is empty"` but `IsEmpty` wasn't working. Another thing that I have looked at was `pattern matching,` but again, I don't know how it would work with my specific function. [F# Check if a list is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52366080/f-check-if-a-list-is-empty)

Any help would be appreciated, and thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your list always two elements? Or is it arbitrarily long?

Comment: @EliemerVelez it is always two elements

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most elegant approach is to use pattern matching, which lets you check that the list has exactly two elements and extract their values:

```
let vSum list = 
  match list with
  | [(x1, y1); (x2, y2)] -> vAdd (x1, y1) (x2, y2)
  | _ -> failwith "The list did not have two elements!"
```

You can slightly shorten this by using the `function` keyword, which is a shortcut for a function taking a variable and pattern matching on it:

```
let vSum = function
  | [(x1, y1); (x2, y2)] -> vAdd (x1, y1) (x2, y2)
  | _ -> failwith "The list did not have two elements!"
```

That said, if you always want to pass around two things, you should not be using a list, but use a tuple instead. You can have a tuple of tuples - that is fine - but if you know it is exactly two elements, then using a list is breaking the rule "make invalid states unrepresentable".

Comment: Something becomes a rule, because we break the rule, otherwise it would be a law. But yes, besides nitpicking i agree fully what you say.

Comment: We should really work on making "make invalid states unrepresentable" a law. Not a legal law, but a law of physics or, even better, a mathematical law! Then only the [Australian governmnet](https://www.newscientist.com/article/2140747-laws-of-mathematics-dont-apply-here-says-australian-pm/) will be able to break it.

Comment: Dr. Strange moved Australia from another multiverse in our World. That's why mathematics in Australia is special! Personally i think invalid states should be to 98% unrepresentable.